# Barplot show only one data

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm working on data `elo_blatter` from the the `fivethirtyeight` package. I want to make barplot of sources of gdp and population I made this code for ex for population:

```
popus <- elo_blatter %>% count(popu_source = replace(popu_source, grep('wikipedia', popu_source), 'Wikipedia'))
```

data:

[image]

Now i try to do boxplot:

```
barplot(table(popus$n, popus$popu_source), beside = FALSE, 
    col = my_colors, border = "white", ylim = c(0, 2),
    cex.axis = 0.8, cex.names = 0.8, las = 2, cex.main = 1,
    main = "something")
```

But it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check which is the outcome of `table(popus$n, popus$popu_source)`, as you could see, it's a matrix that shows "1" when a combination of `popus$n`, `popus$popu_source` exists in the dataset.

That's the reason why you're having barplots that are flat in "1".

**How to solve that?**

```
barplot(popus$n, border=F , names.arg=popus$popu_source)
```

[image]

With that, you will have a barplot showing the values of `n`, with the names of `popu_source`. If you want to make it more beautiful, check the documentation of `barplot` function.

This link may help you with that: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/37-barplot-with-number-of-observation.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use `setNames` to plot a named vector, `barplot` will take care of putting those names as x axis labels.

```
setNames(popus$n, popus$popu_source)
#       IMF CIA (2007)  Wikipedia World Bank 
#         1          5          5        198 

barplot(setNames(popus$n, popus$popu_source), border = "white")
```

[image]

**Data**

```
popus <- data.frame(popu_source = c('IMF', 'CIA (2007)', ' Wikipedia', 'World Bank'),
                    n = c(1, 5, 5, 198))
```